# Powershell's Get-ChildItem cannot see OneDrive's Online-Only files

Tags: powershell, system.io.fileinfo, onedrive

How to retrieve in Powershell the file info of Windows 8.1's special kind of OneDrive files, the Online-only files?

While Windows Explorer provides the typical file info (like date modified, file type, and size) for all files on OneDrive, Powershell's Get-ChildItem cmdlet only "sees" those OneDrive files, that are available offline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem -Force` and you'll find also those items which are not available offline.

They are available as hidden files, so you need your command to show hidden files.

If I compare the attributes, on my computer, for files which are available offline and those which are online only, I can see the following:

*Offline:*

```
Archive
```

*Online only:*

```
Hidden, System, Archive, SparseFile, ReparsePoint, Offline
```